# R color scatter plot with more color gradiant

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

Hello I have Dataframe ploting scatter plot with color using other column values plot is looking fine but the colour values are start from 0-100 and most of the values are in between 50-100 so I wanted put more color to diffrentiat can any one suggest me how can I do with the R, I tried with viridis color it is also looking same 50-100 color is almost looking similar color

link for the data

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EKhRwup3vUC3KVFOOh4XtKERIr8FQj3x/view?usp=sharing

code what I tried

```
df=read.table("test.txt",sep='\t', header=TRUE)
df = data.frame(df)

p=ggplot(df, aes(log(data1), log(data2)),cex=1.9)+
  geom_point(aes(color =data3)) +
  theme(legend.position = "top")+
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"))+
  theme(text = element_text(size = 20, face="bold"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can play with a customized color palette and `scale_colour_gradientn` like this:

```
library(RColorBrewer)
library(ggplot2)
#Data
df <- read.delim(file='test.txt',stringsAsFactors = F)
#Palette
myPalette <- colorRampPalette(rev(brewer.pal(11, "Spectral")))
sc <- scale_colour_gradientn(colours = myPalette(100))
#Plot
ggplot(df, aes(log(data1), log(data2)),cex=1.9)+
  geom_point(aes(color =data3)) + sc +
  theme(legend.position = "top")+
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"))+
  theme(text = element_text(size = 20, face="bold"))
```

Output:

[image]

If you want more color try this:

```
#Palette 2
sc2 <- scale_colour_gradientn(colours = rainbow(7))
#Plot
ggplot(df, aes(log(data1), log(data2)),cex=1.9)+
  geom_point(aes(color =data3)) + sc2 +
  theme(legend.position = "top")+
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"))+
  theme(text = element_text(size = 20, face="bold"))
```

Output:

[image]

**Update2:** With `breaks` you can define limits for the color scale:

```
#Plot 3
ggplot(df, aes(log(data1), log(data2),color=data3),cex=1.9)+
  geom_point() +
  scale_colour_gradientn(colours = rainbow(25),breaks = seq(0,100,by=5))+
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"))+
  theme(text = element_text(size = 12, face="bold"),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 7, face="bold"))
```

Output:

[image]

**Update 3:** If you want to have different colors you can mix different palettes like this:

```
#Plot
ggplot(df, aes(log(data1), log(data2),color=data3),cex=1.9)+
  geom_point() +
  scale_colour_gradientn(colours = c(viridis::inferno(5),
                                     viridis::plasma(5),
                                     viridis::magma(5),
                                     viridis::viridis(5),
                                     rainbow(5)),breaks = seq(0,100,by=5))+
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"))+
  theme(text = element_text(size = 12, face="bold"),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 7, face="bold"))
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Duck But the problem is wanted more gradient through legend bin if we see I wanted put gradient breaks line 0-5, 5-10..95-100 like that is it possible

Comment: @Hemantchandrunaik Great! I will add another option for more color. If you think this answer was useful, you could accept it by clicking the tick on the left side of this answer. It is up to you :)

Comment: @Hemantchandrunaik I have added additional code. I hope that helps !

Comment: Okay thanks using our values breaks which  I am trying to do the colour is it possible put color scale on that

Comment: @Hemantchandrunaik I have added a new update with the breaks you want! Please check and let me know if that works!

Comment: Thank you for you suggestion other than rainbow is there any other gradient like in viridis

Comment: @Hemantchandrunaik Yes you can set any color palette you want! The same viridis can work for you! So did last update solve your issue?

Comment: I tried with viridis its looking same. its not looking like plot3 can you please suggest me

Comment: @Hemantchandrunaik I have added a new update that teach you how to mix colors from different viridis palettes. Hope that helps. Please if you think the answer is useful you could accept it. There is a deep range of solutions for you :)

Comment: Thank you so much I am not getting goog source of study material with my search, Thanks a lot for your help and support. if you suggest me any source for understanding it will be very helful

Comment: @Hemantchandrunaik Look for at `ggplot2` page in the section for `scale_colour_gradientn()` :)